# Capacity of roads in OSMnx

Tags: osmnx

Are there any attributes to weigh the edges of the network (roadways) based on their capacity? For example, the number of lanes for each roadway or the maximum capacity of driveways.

Answer (score 1):

Lanes is often available: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:lanes

For example from here: https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L6/network-analysis.html

```
# Retrieve only edges from the graph
 edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=False, edges=True)


# Check columns
edges.columns

Index(['u', 'v', 'key', 'osmid', 'oneway', 'lanes', 'name', 'highway',
       'maxspeed', 'length', 'geometry', 'junction', 'bridge', 'access'],
      dtype='object'

print(edges['lanes'].value_counts())
```

Comment: Out of a large number of answers on how to extract the number of lanes from OSM using osmnx, this is probably the only answer on SO that works as of March, 2022!