# Max Road Capacity using OSMnx

Tags: python, osmnx

I am trying to calculate the maximum road capacity of a city road network in OSMNX. I am new to OSMNX so there are several things that are unclear to me.

The formulas I want to use is the sum for all road in the network of $(L_s/L_v)*N_l$

where $L_s$ is the length of a road, $L_v$ is the average vehicle length occupancy, and $N_l$ is the number of lanes in this road.

For now what I have is

```
G = ox.graph_from_place("Riyadh, Saudi Arabia", network_type="drive")
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False, edges=True)


# Check columns
edges.columns

# Index(['u', 'v', 'key', 'osmid', 'oneway', 'lanes', 'name', 'highway',
#        'maxspeed', 'length', 'geometry', 'junction', 'bridge', 'access'],
#       dtype='object')

print(edges['lanes'].value_counts())
```

Taken from [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200805/capacity-of-roads-in-osmnx)

What I got is this

```
lanes
2         2747
3         2041
1          531
4          373
[3, 2]       9
5            7
[1, 3]       3
[3, 4]       3
[4, 3]       2
[1, 2]       2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

I understand that this is the count of lanes of each type but, I mainly have two questions:
First, what does it mean when the lanes are given in this format [3, 2], as opposed to one number?

The second and most important question is is there a way to multiply road length from the GeoDataFrame of graph edges by the number of lanes and then sum all the roads together to get the formula above? To be clear what I want is to say something like "the roads of this city have a max capacity of 1,000,000 cars at a time".

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your first question: when OSMnx simplifies a graph, "Some of the resulting consolidated edges may comprise multiple OSM ways, and if so, their multiple attribute values are stored as a list" per [the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html#osmnx.simplification.simplify_graph).

Comment: @gboeing So does that in this case mean that [3, 2] is a two 3 lane roads? which makes them 6?

Comment: No, it means that OSMnx found the values 2 and 3 in the lanes attributes for the ways it merged into that edge. That is, some part of it had 2 lanes and another part had 3 lanes. You can set simplify=False to avoid merging ways into edges.